# Calculating optimal transport container space allocation

Tags: iphone, algorithm, math, optimization

I would consider hiring a freelancer for this. However, I would like to know more about it or if there is an existing solution (app) for it.

So what is that I am looking for?
- A way to allocate transport container space usage (or should I maybe say: room instead of space)

There are 25 different type of boxes for shipping various items (furniture). I would need an app or an any idea as of how to build one in order to be able to perform optimal space allocation...

Any ideas? - Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sounds like the "Traveling Salesman" problem. Get *Algorithms* by Sedgewick.

Comment: @Zaph Seems to me like a variation of multidimensional knapsack, not TSP. What are the towns in the reduction you had in mind?

Comment: Probably so, I didn't really think to hard on my comment. The towns would be the boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or [binpacking problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) on 3D instead of 1D weights. This problem is NP-Hard, and there is no known efficient exact solution for it (1D knapsack has a pseudo-polynomial solution, but not mutidimensional, which is [strong NP-Hard problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21865/6287)).

One pretty simple approach to solve it (get a "good" solution,even though it is not optimal) would be using AI algorithms, such as [Genetic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)s or [Hill-Climbin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing)g, the idea is to "smartly" manipulate a random allocation of the furniture and re-try large amount of times, while remembering the best solutions.

More solutions can be found in [this survey](http://www.m-hikari.com/asb/asb2012/asb1-4-2012/jalaliASB1-4-2012-1.pdf)

Comment: There is a survey specific to containers at http://www.fww.ovgu.de/fww_media/femm/femm_2012/2012_07.pdf. Since it says "the state-of-the-art in the area of container loading is not convincing. Modeling approaches to the various problem types are few. In particular with respect to the inclusion of practically-relevant constraints, research still has to be looked upon as being in its infancy" I would also suggest putting your work into identifying constraints and then using a general heuristic such as iterated hillclimbing, GRASP, or Late Acceptance Hill Climbing.